# Is it possible to combine mysql and mongodb databases for sorting

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, sorting, filter

in our project we are using mysql and mongodb.
Our primary database mysql but for some reasons we are using mongodb for specific modules.
Now we are facing issue with Sorting and filtering.
we are storing details in mongodb like `{ companies: [1, 2, 4, 10], project: 15, users: [45, 34, 3] }`
and in mysql we are storing company name, project name and user name.
But here we need to filter and sort depend on the configured condition. its a dynamic report.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. A join in the sql sense between mysql and mongodb data is not possible, these are two separate systems. But of course you can programmatically sort the result of one query based on the data of the other query. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @simon.ro our database holds nearly billion of records. so are not possible to sort programmatically. coz its has huge records its may took more time to complete the process and also its require multiple queries to run. so am checking it is possible to combine both database using any tools ?

Comment: Even a tool that offers a common facade cannot do anything other than execute separate queries.

Comment: @simon.ro my main concern. we using pagination so only fetching 50 records at a time. but every reports has nearly million of records. so for 50 records we actually need to get all of the data from database also needed to run same query multiple times. its totally waste of time then also we need to return 50 records within 3 seconds of time slap

Comment: Your question is really unclear. In many cases you could use PHP to bridge the gap between two database systems, but I can imagine some cases where this is no longer efficient. In those cases the advice has to be to convert one database to the other and use a single database system.